# How to get N greatest elements out of M elements using CUDA, where N << M?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, cuda

I am just wondering whether there is any efficient ways of getting N greatest elements out of M elements, where N is much smaller than M (e.g. N = 10, and M = 1000) using the GPU.

The problem is that - due to the large size of input data, I really do not want to transfer the data from the GPU to the CPU and then get it back. However, exact sorting does not seem to work well because of thread divergence and the time wasted on sorting elements that we do not really care about (in the case above, DC elements are 11 ~ 1000).

Comment: I guess some maximum heaps are typical solution of these problems.

Comment: @halfelf: I wouldn't recommend doing a maximum binary heap on CUDA, if that is what you are refering to? Unless you have some more specific way of doing so on a parallel machine?

Comment: You give an example N=10, M=1000, but you talk about large input data. What are your realistic values for N and M? Depending on N I would suggest either adapting a reduction algorithm or adapting a sorting algorithm. Even for small M, if it is part of a bigger CUDA algorithm, it may be good to do it on the device too.

Comment: See [A FAST PARALLEL SELECTION ALGORITHM ON GPUs](https://www.csuohio.edu/engineering/sites/csuohio.edu.engineering/files/Research_Day_2015_EECS_Poster_14.pdf). There are also a few SO questions about implementing [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) on CUDA, but none with definitive answers.

Answer (score 1):

If N is small enough that the N largest values can be kept in shared memory, that would allow a fast implementation that only reads through your array of M elements in global memory once and then immediately writes out these N largest values. Implementation becomes simpler if N also doesn't exceed the maximum number of threads per block.

Contrary to serial programming, I would not use a heap (or other more complicated data structure), but just a sorted array. There is plenty of parallel hardware on an SM that would go unused when traversing a heap. The entire thread block can be used to shift the elements of the shared memory array that are smaller than the newly incoming value.

If N<=32, a neat solution is possible that keeps a sorted list of the N largest numbers in registers, using [warp shuffle functions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-shuffle-functions).

Comment: Could you elaborate more about what algorithm is adopted? From your description, you mention that keep N largest values in shared memory in the first paragraph, and use registers to keep N largest values in the third paragraph. The second paragraph in your post suggest not use heap data structure. My question is what algorithm you use in getting N greatest elements out of M elements. Thank you